# How to match features based on colour

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction, mosaic

I have a new series of images which I want to match with the old series of images taken at the same place but on different day and orientation. However I am unable to match features using most of the state of the art techniques like SIFT. I would like to match two images based on colours, specifically let's say the stone colour from the circle. I have another image of the same picture with the same stone from another angle. How can I use match these two stones irrespective of orientation based on colour

[image: Sample image with preferred colour for matching in circle]

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/htmp/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use some sort of template matching algorithm. 
I'd recommend using [DDIS](https://github.com/roimehrez/DDIS) - one of the best ones I know.